# Como extraer datos entre un rango de fechas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un fichero txt que contiene datos en diferentes columnas. Los datos se encuentran separados con "|" pero quedan espacios en blanco en las filas debido a que pueden existir diferentes longitudes al rellenar un campo. Ejemplo:

```
*|NOMBRE    | EDAD         |FECHA NACIMIENTO |
*|JUAN      | 28 AÑOS      |23.01.1997       |
*|PEDRO     | 5 AÑOS       |01.06.1997       |
*|ANASTASIA | 16 AÑOS      |19.11.1997       |
```

Quiero separar el `.txt` por cuatrimestres con lo que tengo que hacer un filtro con `FECHA NACIMIENTO`.
Me gustaría saber como poder agrupar los datos de todas las columnas, separados por un rango de fechas (cuatrimestre) en  un nuevo `.txt`
He probado a usar la librería `pandas` y los siguientes ejemplos de código, pero ninguno funciona.

Código 1:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(RutaFechaAgrupado1, encoding = "ANSI")
i = 0
for i in range(4):
   if i == 0:
        #df = df.set_index(["Fecha planificada"])
        filtered_df = df.loc["01.01.2021":"31.03.2021"]
        #selecc = df[df["Fecha planificada"].filtered_df]
                            
        f2 = filtered_df.to_csv(RutaAgrupOrde)
        #f2.write(filtered_df)
                            print(filtered_df)
```

CÓDIGO 2:

Igual pero usando `read_fwf`

El problema de usar `read_fwf` es que me genera una columna inicial que es el índice de la fila, es decir, las enumera. Y desconozco como poder eliminarla.

Comment: Aunque edité la pregunta para añadir correctamente ``` alrededor del código, el resultado muestra un código mal indentado. Por favor revísalo pues tal como está es imposible entender qué se pretendía.

Comment: Listo, gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene el bucle? Iteras 4 veces, pero sólo haces algo cuando `i==0` que es la primera. Además en lo que haces la variable `i` no participa. Por tanto perfectamente puedes quitar `i`, el bucle y el `if` y dejar solo las operaciones pandas. El índice que añade pandas no lo puedes quitar, aunque si vas a volcar a disco el dataframe puedes pedirle que omita el índice (por ejemplo, si vuelcas a csv puedes poner `filtered_df.to_csv(nombre, index=False)`. Al margen de esto, no veo que tu `.loc` esté haciendo lo que pides. Solo estás extrayendo un rango, pero no agrupando por cuatrimestre

Comment: el bucle es porque hay más archivos que se agrupan por diferentes rangos de fecha

Comment: El bucle itera para varios .txt agrupados por diferentes rangos de fechas, el primer problema es que `read_csv` no transmite correctamente los datos al `dataframe` debido a que tiene el separador "|" y los espacios, por lo que responde: `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 23` y no sé como hacer para que omita dichos espacios. Segundo, desconozco como se implementa .loc

Answer (score 0):

Creo que una opción relativamente sencilla sería convertir la columna de fechas en el índice del dataframe, y usar el método `resample()` que automáticamente creará sub-dataframes para las fechas comprendidas en los intervalos que le especifiques (puedes especificar anual, semestral, cuatrimestral, mensual, etc...)

No tengo tu problema completo, pues en un comentario especificas que son varios ficheros los que tienes que procesar. Por ello no puedo darte una respuesta completa, sólo una orientación.

Mi idea sería la siguiente:

1. Lees cada uno de los ficheros en un dataframe. Cómo leerlos depende del formato que realmente tenga el fichero. Si el formato es como el que muestras al inicio (columnas separadas por un `|` y una primera columna con asteriscos) la forma de leerlos podría ser así:

   ```py
   df = pd.read_csv(fichero, sep=r"\s*\|\s*").drop(columns=["*", "Unnamed: 4"])
   ```

   En tu caso, ya que dices que son varios ficheros, podrías hacer un bucle para ir leyendo cada uno, e ir metiendo los `df` en una lista, así por ejemplo:

   ```
   nombres_ficheros = ["fichero1.csv", "fichero2.csv", "fichero3.csv"]
   lista = []
   for fichero in nombres_ficheros:
       df = pd.read_csv(fichero, sep=r"\s*\|\s*").drop(columns=["*", "Unnamed: 4"])
       lista.append(df)
   ```
2. Concatena todos los `df` leidos en uno solo:

   ```
   todo = pd.concat(lista)
   ```
3. Convierte la columna de fechas al tipo datetime, y asígnalo como índice del dataframe:

   ```
   todo["FECHA NACIMIENTO"] = pd.to_datetime(todo["FECHA NACIMIENTO"])
   todo.set_index("FECHA NACIMIENTO")
   ```

Y ahora ya podemos agrupar por cuatrimestres e iterar por ellos. Para cada iteración podemos por ejemplo imprimir el dataframe por pantalla, o guardarlo en otro csv o lo que necesites. En el siguiente ejemplo los muestro por pantalla:

```
for grupo in todo.resample("Q"):  # Q sigifica cuatrimestre
   print(grupo[1])
   print("-"*60)  # Separador
```

Si aplico esto sobre el mini-ejemplo que pusiste en la pregunta sale lo siguiente:

```html
                 NOMBRE     EDAD
FECHA NACIMIENTO                
1997-01-06        PEDRO   5 AÑOS
1997-01-23         JUAN  28 AÑOS
------------------------------------------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [NOMBRE, EDAD]
Index: []
------------------------------------------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [NOMBRE, EDAD]
Index: []
------------------------------------------------------------
                     NOMBRE     EDAD
FECHA NACIMIENTO                    
1997-11-19        ANASTASIA  16 AÑOS
------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Nota** Observa que se genera un grupo por cada cuatrimestre, incluso si en ese cuatrimestre no hay entradas, como sucede de hecho en este caso para los cuatrimestres dos y tres.